# How to use hidden column data of jTable in tooltip

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I am trying to display the data of hidden column as tooltip. Hiding is working perfectly using the following code:

```
    JTable table = new JTable(model){
        //Implement table cell tool tips.          
        public String getToolTipText(MouseEvent e) {
            String tip = null;
            java.awt.Point p = e.getPoint();
            int rowIndex = rowAtPoint(p);
            int colIndex = columnAtPoint(p);
            int realColumnIndex = convertColumnIndexToModel(colIndex);

            try {
                tip = getValueAt(rowIndex, 8).toString();
            } catch (RuntimeException e1) {
                //catch null pointer exception if mouse is over an empty line
            }

            return tip;
        }
    };

    TableColumnModel tcm = table.getColumnModel();

    TableColumn tc;
    for(int i = 1; i <= 7; i++){
        tc = tcm.getColumn(8);
        tcm.removeColumn(tc);
    }
```

But the tooltip is not showing the data of hidden column (getValue function is not returning value). So do hiding the column delete the data as well ?

Answer (score 5):

1. You do not need to for loop as you do not use the `i` variable ;-)
2. The `removeColumn` on the [`JTable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29) does not remove the data from the model, as clearly stated in the javadoc

   > Removes aColumn from this JTable's array of columns. Note: this method does not remove the column of data from the model; it just removes the TableColumn that was responsible for displaying it.

   There is no mention in the javadoc for the same method on the [`TableColumnModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableColumnModel.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29), but I would assume it works the same way, but you can always give it a try to call it on the `JTable` instead
3. The real problem in your code is the use of `getValueAt`, which uses the row and column index of the table, and not of the model

   > Note: The column is specified in the table view's display order, and not in the TableModel's column order. This is an important distinction because as the user rearranges the columns in the table, the column at a given index in the view will change. Meanwhile the user's actions never affect the model's column ordering.

   And since you removed that column, it simply does not exists for the table. Call the [`getValue`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableModel.html#getValueAt%28int,%20int%29) method on the model instead, and do not forget to convert the [row index](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#convertRowIndexToModel%28int%29)